Align Y axis start for subplots in pyqtgraph
I want to align the line indicating the start of the Y axis.  As you can see in the image the middle plot is out of line with the top and bottom plot.  Apparently because they take up varying amount of space due to the length of the displayed axis values.


Please provide a [mre]

You can use setWidth as described here
